# Mongodb wrong return from Mycollection.find().count();

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

i have a problem with my app.
When written this db.request.count(); on mongo shell i have 4, but when i written Request.find().count() in my js code i have 0.
Someone can help me ?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same mongoDB? When meteor starts, it boots up its own personal MongoDB instance, that is likely to be separate from a Mongo server you set up personally.

Comment: What is `Request`? Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: Can you show parts of your code which are connected with counting your documents(publication, subscription)? Did you subscribe to the publication on your client side?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Request.count()` instead of calling `count()` after `find()`.

This is assuming the name of your model is `Request`.

[The Mongoose documentation has examples here.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count)

Answer (score 1):

If you ran `Request.find().count()` on the client and got `0`, it's most likely that your client-side code did not subscribe to the `Request` collection.

If you ran `Request.find().count()` on the server and got `0`, make sure you connected to the correct database. I.e. Meteor creates its own Mongo instance on port `3001`, whilst you may have been using a different database on `27017`.